# Rails 3: Many-to-Many relation with condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

I have the following models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_members
  has_many :members, :through => :project_members, :uniq => true,:class_name => "User",  :source => :user
  has_many :admins, :through => :project_members, :uniq => true, :conditions => ['project_members.admin = ?', true], :class_name => "User", :source => :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # References
  has_many :project_members
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_members

end
```

and the join table

```
class ProjectMember < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The relations seem to work, but when I want to add an admin to a project via this code

```
project.admins.push(u)
project.save
```

(where u is a User) it saves the new relationship but without setting admin to true in the join table.

Even if I retrieve this relation from the project and setting admin to true manually by doing

```
project.project_members.first.admin = true
```

and saving the project it doens't update the attribute in the table.

What am I doing wrong? (Please keep in mind that I'm a total beginner with ruby and rails)
I have been googling for the last hours to find a solution but couldn't find anything :/

Comment: Don't expect too much magic from Rails. On "saving the project it doens't update the attribute in the table": saves do not cascade (they only do on creation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to change your admins association to :

```
has_many :admins, :through => :project_members, :uniq => true, :conditions => {:project_members => {:admin => true}}, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: I already tried that, but as the admin attribute is in the through table and not in the users table it fails with the following error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.admin: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_members" ON "users".id = "project_members".user_id WHERE (("project_members".project_id = 3) AND (("users"."admin" = 't'))) LIMIT 1
`

Comment: sorry about that use :conditions => {:project_members => {:admin => true}}

Comment: Thanks, that works (like my version before) but it still doens't set admin to true if I do `p.admins << user`. Or would this never automatically work? What would I have to do, to be able to add admins like this and the admin attribute is set automatically to true?

Comment: Hello, does it create an admin user if you do `project.admins.create(params[:user])` ?

Comment: It would create a new User, I have now settled with the following way: `@creator = @project.project_members.build(:admin => true) @creator.user = current_user @creator.save`